# How can store variable while select query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, select, global-variables

I have a LINQ query like this:

```
var q = from p in m.TblOzvs.AsEnumerable()
        where (p.OzviyatNumber == txtSearch.Text) 
        select new mylist
        {                     
            Col1 = p.OzviyatNumber.ToString(),
            Col2 = p.Name,
            Col3 = Calculate._RPMajmoSoodeGhest(p.OzviyatNumber)[1],
            Col4 = Calculate._RPMajmoSoodeGhest(p.OzviyatNumber)[0]
        };
```

As you can see, for `Col3` and `Col4` I need to call a function that returns an array of strings where `string[1]` is for `Col3` and `string[0]` is for `Col4`.

I was wondering if there is any way to call `Calculate._RPMajmoSoodeGhest()` 1 time and use it for both `Col3` and `Col4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 'let' to define a quantity that you can reference in the 'select' portion of the query:

```
var q = from p in m.TblOzvs.AsEnumerable()
         where (p.OzviyatNumber == txtSearch.Text) 
         let calcVal = Calculate._RPMajmoSoodeGhest(p.OzviyatNumber)
         select new mylist
         {                     
             Col1 = p.OzviyatNumber.ToString(),
             Col2 = p.Name,
             Col3 =  calcVal[1],              
             Col4 = calcVal[0]
         };
```